# Fancybox/ColorBox/etc

Tags: javascript, lightbox, fancybox-2

I need some kind of lightbox (Fancybox/ColorBox) to show a YouTube video. I put the demo in the same location where I have the other files and it works just fine. The thing is, when I copy everything to the file which needs the Fancybox it doesn't work, it just opens the YouTube link.

This is probably easy to solve, but I am a noob in this subject. Any ideas?

My version: http://pastebin.com/3rNTD0kT

Fancybox demo: http://pastebin.com/uceBdWcT

Comment: Are getting any console errors (Check Firebug or Chrome's console)?

Comment: thanks @mcryan it solved it. i forgot one folder on the path. didnt knew i could see the errors using that, again thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you came right.

Comment: @Kipz: If you think it's worth to document for future users, please leave your solution as an answer and accept it later. If not, please delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure your files are in the Right Path.

2)jquery-1.9.0.min.js & jquery.min.js called twice in your version. That may clash//create some conflict.

3)your code calling/including css may be having some problem...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
```

Here in this code.. look at src=""
that should be src="./fancybox/...." or
   if the folde is in the sane folder where the html file is then you may have like this
    src="fancybox/...."

I hope this may help :)